# Laravel groupby and count different values (Polymorphic)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with the name "reportable" and want to display the entries in a table on the website. Unfortunately I can't get the database query right, I don't have much experience with a One To Many (Polymorphic) table.

databse table:

```
Schema::create('reportable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->integer('reason');
            $table->integer('reportable_id')->index();
            $table->string('reportable_type')->index();
            $table->text('notice')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0)->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In the table on the web page I want to display only entries with the same reportable_id and reportable_type only once.

In addition, the entries with the same reportable_id and reportable_type should be counted and displayed as a numerical value.

In addition, the entries in the column 'reason' with the same reportable_id and reportable_type should be counted and displayed with the respective entry and as a numerical value.

Comment: Please provide details on what queries you've tried and how the results differed from expected. Otherwise this just sounds like a "do my work" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a list:

```
    $query = Report::select(\DB::raw('reportable.reportable_id,reportable.reportable_type,SUM(reason) as reason_total'))  // Or \DB::raw('reportable.*,SUM(reason) as reason_total')
        ->groupBy('reportable_type')
        ->groupBy('reportable_id')
        ->get();
```

And if you want to have a specific row you should have your query like this:

```
    $reportableId = 1; // $reportableId = Input::get('report_id'); // It can come from get parameters     http://localhost/reports?report_id= 1
    $reportableType = 'User'; 

    $query = Report::select(\DB::raw('reportable.reportable_id,reportable.reportable_type,SUM(reason) as reason_total'))  // Or \DB::raw('reportable.*,SUM(reason) as reason_total')
        ->groupBy('reportable_type')
        ->groupBy('reportable_id')
        ->get();


    if($reportableId)
        $query =  $query->where('reportable_id' , $reportableId );

    if($reportableType)
        $query =  $query->where('reportable_type' , $reportableType );

    return $query;
```